# How to enable decimal values in Django template?

Tags: django, templates

the problem is when is use add filter i get a raw result or a round off result like say
10 + 0.2 = 10 only (instead i want it to print 10.2). My models.py and templates file below

models.py

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
```

i filled the value of price in database as 5.

home.html

```
{{ object.price }}
```

it prints 5 (good)
but when i use filter -> {{ object.price|add:0.2 }}
it returns 10 (i want 10.2) on my homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django `add` template tag will first try to coerce both values to integers.

From Django builtin tags [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add)

> This filter will first try to coerce both values to integers. If this
>   fails, it’ll attempt to add the values together anyway. This will work
>   on some data types (strings, list, etc.) and fail on others. If it
>   fails, the result will be an empty string.

If you desire your behavior you should create your own [custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

---

```
@register.filter
def addfloat(value, arg):
    return float(value) + float(arg)
```

Comment: any ideas where to start from as i found documentation in not that good in terms of providing examples. Its very straight forward in my opinion.

Comment: Documentation for custom tag has enough examples and tag is fairly easy to write